# Codeigniter custom routing issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

This is my routes setup code

```
$route['general/(:any)'] = "videos/filter/$1/1"; 
$route['general/(:any)/(:num)'] = "videos/filter/$1/1/$2"; //pagination
```

Following link works fine.

```
www.example.com/general/latest
```

But below link doesn't work like what i want

```
www.example.com/general/latest-trending/5
```

$route['general/(:any)'] only executes always.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the order:

```
$route['general/(:any)/(:num)'] = "videos/filter/$1/1/$2"; //pagination
$route['general/(:any)'] = "videos/filter/$1/1";
```

You want more specific routes first, because if the shorter one matches first, it will ignore all other routes.